# How can I prevent the browser from scrolling to top of the page when checking the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I know we can find lots of similar questions on stackoverflow. I am using ReactJS.

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
          <p>Check 1</p>
          <a></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
          <p>Check 2</p>
          <a></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Here is an example of what I am using. there are above 35 checkboxes, and whenever I am clicking on any one of them the page is jumping to top.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

As I have tried on simple html page with 100 checkboxes, its working fine but in my React code. There is jump

Here is how I am handling change event:

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange={this.props.checkedList} name="article" value={item.id}/>

 checkedList(e) {
let id = e.target.value
if (this.state.marked.includes(id)) {
  let filteredArray = this.state.marked.filter(item => item !== id)
  this.setState({marked: filteredArray});
}
else {
  this.setState({marked: this.state.marked.concat(id)});
}
}
```

Comment: How are you handling the Check event?

Comment: As you are calling setState in the event, it will render the component again

Comment: @RichaGarg Commenting the lines worked but can u tell me how should I keep the track of checked items

Comment: Can you please share your entire code. The state `marked` is for the parent component, which when changed will render it again.

Comment: @RichaGarg I cannot post more code as it is huge, can you show me some examples of how checkbox values are stored in React js. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141520/discussion-between-rahul-shrivastava-and-richa-garg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are calling setState in the event, it is causing the component to render which has the state `marked`. You should use the local variable in the component to handle the array marked or handle the `shouldComponentUpdate`. You can find details [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#shouldcomponentupdate-in-action) to how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `aria-label="test"`.

Example:

```
<input  aria-label="test" id="test" type="checkbox" />
```

> The aria-label attribute is used to define a string that labels the
>   current element. Use it in cases where a text label is not visible on
>   the screen. (If there is visible text labeling the element, use
>   aria-labelledby instead.)

Reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute

Comment: I used label also and aria-label also but its not helping